# Relation between symmetries and Killing vectors by Weinberg

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor

In his book, "Gravity and Cosmology", Weinberg talks about relations between homogeneous metric spaces and Klling vectors. First he says about infinitesimal isometrics
$$
x^{\alpha}{'} = x^{\alpha} + \varepsilon k_{\lambda}{}^\alpha. \qquad (1)
$$
Then he gets Killing equations and a fact that each of Killing vectors $k_{\lambda}$ can be represented near point X as Taylor series
$$
k_{\lambda}{}^\mu (X, x) = A_{\lambda}{}^\nu (X, x) k_{\nu}{}^\mu + B_{\lambda}{}^{\rho \delta}D_{\rho}(X, x) k_{\delta}{}^\mu, \quad A, B \neq f(k_{\lambda}).
$$
Then he gives the definition of homogeneous spaces: they are the spaces which refer to the existence of isometries $(1)$ which make parallel shifts from point X to any point of its surroundings. By the other words, he says, it means that this property of space requiers that the **metric of corresponding space must have Killing vectors which can take all possible values ​​at any given point X**. So it leads to the statement that **in N-dimensional space we can choose N Killing vectors which have the property** 
$$
k_{\lambda}{}^\mu(X, X) = \delta_{\lambda}^{\mu}.
$$
I don't understand words in italics. Can you explain them to me?

Comment: Instead of using `\quad`, try breaking apart indices with `{}` instead. Thus, `$\delta_\lambda{}^\mu$` produces $\delta_\lambda{}^\mu$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, Weinberg p. 378:

> A metric space is said to be *homogeneous* if there exist infinitesimal isometries (13.1.3) that carry any given point $X$ into any other point in its immediate neighborhood.

Equation (13.1.3) defines an infinitesimal transformation and (13.1.5) concludes the Killing equation $\xi_{\sigma;\rho} + \xi_{\rho;\sigma} = 0$ from it. Now, pick a particular point $X$. By the quoted definition, every direction from $X$ is fair game, so there must exist some Killing vector fields $\xi^{\mu}$ whose values at $X$ form a basis for the $X$'s tangent space.

Thus, we can write any vector at $X$ as a linear combination of $\xi^{(\mu)}(X)$, any take the coefficients to define a new vector field $K$. By linearity of the Lie derivative, $K$ is a Killing vector field, $$\mathcal{L}_K(g) = \sum_\mu a_{(\mu)}\mathcal{L}_{\xi^{(\mu)}}(g) = \sum_\mu a_{(\mu)}(0) = 0\text{.}$$

> That is, the metric must admit Killing vectors that at any given point take all possible values.

By construction, the value of $K$ at $X$ is whatever vector we started with. Since it was arbitrary, we can have a Killing vector field that takes any value we want at $X$.

> In particular, in an $N$-dimensional space we can choose a set of $N$ Killing vectors $\xi_\lambda {}^{(\mu)}(x;X)$ with $\xi_\lambda {}^{(\mu)}(X;X) = \delta_\lambda{}^\mu$.

Okay, $\xi_\rho{}^{(\mu)}(x;X)$ is the $\rho$-component of $\xi^{(\mu)}$ at $x$ written in terms of the value of the Killing vector field (and its derivatives) at $X$. So all it means is that we can have Killing vector fields whose values at $X$ are the coordinate vectors, $$\xi^{(\mu)}|_X = \partial_\mu|_X = \delta^{\lambda\mu}\partial_\lambda|_X\text{.}$$ That follows from the $K$-construction above, one for each of them individually.